# View before Tab Bar View

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I have TabBar View combined with Navigation View. 
Structure like this:
delegate -> TabBar -> (many) Navigation Views -> (many for each) Controller Views.

I want show one view (config) before any other view. I want this view without Bars and Navigation Controlls. 
It is possible? How I can do this ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's very possible. In your applicationDidFinishLaunching method, simply make your config view the root view controller like this:

```
UIViewController *configVC = [[ConfigVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConfigVC" bundle:nil];  
[[self window] setRootViewController:configVC];
[configVC release];
```

and then, some later time when you are ready to show the tab bar, do:

```
[[self window] setRootViewController:tabBarViewController];
```

**UPDATE:**
You can access the application delegate like this: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`
After this, you can cast it to your app delegate to avoid any warnings, and then call the method that loads the tab bar...

Comment: Thanks. But i don' t understand one think. I want use last of Your code line in configVC. I can' t use [self window] there. I don' t have any bugs, but program don' t works.

Comment: I want use this: [[self window] setRootViewController:tabBarViewController];
after button click in configVC. From there I can' t get [self window] (and generally delegate). But I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand, you have a tabbar based application and you want to display a view  in the start of your application, You can just display that page as modalviewcontroller and hide navigationbar and status bar.

Comment: That's a bad way of doing this.